# Writing EXIF XPKEYWORDS with Sanselan

Tags: java, exif

I've been researching ways to write tags to my images similar to how Windows Live Photo Gallery works. I've played with several different libraries (metadata-extractor,jhead,jheader,sanselan) but have only really found Sanselan to accomodate writing the data back in that I need.

I followed Apache's [WriteExifMetadataExample](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging//xref-test/org/apache/sanselan/sampleUsage/WriteExifMetadataExample.html) to a T & It worked flawlessly for updating the GPS data and Aperture.

I then attempted to modify the example to update `EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS` rather than `EXIF_TAG_APERTURE_VALUE`.

In the above-linked example, I replaced the `TiffOutputField.create` line with the following:

```
String currentTagsAsString = new String((byte[]) jpegMetadata.findEXIFValue(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS).getValue());
System.out.println("current tags: '" + currentTagsAsString + "'");
String newTag = "h e l l o";
String newTagsAsString = currentTagsAsString.trim() + " ; " + newTag + "   ";
System.out.println("new desired tags: '" + newTagsAsString + "'");
TiffOutputField keywords = new TiffOutputField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS, FieldType.FIELD_TYPE_BYTE, newTagsAsString.length(), newTagsAsString.getBytes());
exifDirectory.removeField(ExifTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS);
exifDirectory.add(keywords);
```

Other than commenting out the aperature and GPS update code, the rest I left alone. I will admit the format of the byte array has me a little confused so that may very well be the issue.

I get no warnings/errors/etc. The process completes normally but the new Image file does not contain the updated tags. Why does the new image not contain the updated tags? Is there an easier/better way?

*UPDATE: I have edited the code to work with the 1.0 RC commons-imaging API instead, however the results are the same. I am including the code I used here for completeness*

```
TiffImageMetadata metadata = toTiffMetadata(Imaging.getMetadata(inputFile));
System.out.println(metadata.getFieldValue(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS));
TiffOutputSet outputSet = metadata.getOutputSet();
TiffOutputDirectory exif = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
exif.removeField(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS);
exif.add(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS, "helloworld;goodbye;");
writeFileWithNewTag(inputFile,destinationFile,outputSet);
```

*The new code works great if i use something like `EXIF_TAG_XPAUTHOR`, but using `EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS` produces no errors or warnings or messages of any kind and the new file simply doens't contain the new tag data*

Comment: I have found that my string formatting was a little off. The actual encoding of the original byte array does not include space characters, but instead the '0' byte.  I have adjusted the code accordingly still with no luck.

Comment: Have you found a way to do this? That is: create new / update / overwrite the XPKEYWORDS?
If not I might have found one. But rather than just posting mine I'd like to compare my approach to yours. Just to see what's different.
I will soon post it here in any case.

Answer (score 4):

I successfully add the XP keywords tag with this code:

```
private static void rewriteXpKeywords(String fileIn, String fileOut) throws Exception {
    TiffImageMetadata exif;
    IImageMetadata meta = Imaging.getMetadata(new File(fileIn));
    if (meta instanceof JpegImageMetadata) {
        exif = ((JpegImageMetadata)meta).getExif();
    } else if (meta instanceof TiffImageMetadata) {
        exif = (TiffImageMetadata)meta;
    } else {
        return;
    }
    TiffOutputSet outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();
    TiffOutputDirectory exifDir = outputSet.findDirectory(TiffDirectoryConstants.DIRECTORY_TYPE_EXIF);
    exifDir.removeField(AllTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS);
    exifDir.add(AllTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS, "helloworld;goodbye;");

    ExifRewriter rewriter = new ExifRewriter();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileOut));
        rewriter.updateExifMetadataLossy(new File(fileIn), fos, outputSet);
    } finally {
        if (fos != null) {
            fos.close();
        }
    }
}
```

How do you know that it doesn't "modify the data"? What are you checking it with?

Comment: I'll give this a shot tonight but it doesn't look much different. I'm checking by using the same Java code to read the newly created file (thus print the existing keywords at the begining) and the keywords remain the same as they were in the original file.

Comment: the one difference I just noticed is you are doing 'outputSet.findDirectory' rather than 'outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory' like my code does. I was thinking last night that the directory i'm attempting to store it to may be incorrect... maybe that's the issue.

Comment: nope no luck. I'm now using your code with a println thrown in: System.out.println(exif.getFieldValue(MicrosoftTagConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS));

Comment: just as a sanity check I ran another test on one of the supposed edited images and dumped all EXIF data for all directories... it's definitely not in there.

Comment: soooo... I ran another test with a newly created image and it works. Any clue why I'd see the behavior I see with some images but not all?

Comment: No idea. Attach an image that works and an image that doesn't?

Comment: Have you given up or can I see an image that doesn't get updated?

Comment: haven't given up yet. I'll try to attach them tonight.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and got the solution. You can give a try to below code

```
public static TiffOutputField getTiffOutputFieldKeyword(
TiffOutputSet outputSet, String metaDataToChange) {
TiffOutputField imageHistoryPre = outputSet
    .findField(TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS);
 if (imageHistoryPre != null) {
outputSet.removeField(TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS);
 }

 TiffOutputField tiffOutputField = new TiffOutputField(
    TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS,
    TiffFieldTypeConstants.FIELD_TYPE_BYTE,
    metaDataToChange.getBytes("UTF-16").length, metaDataToChange.getBytes("UTF-16"));

return tiffOutputField;
}
```

[Writing XPKeywords in Exif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603990/writing-xpkeywords-in-exif/25639015#25639015)

Answer (score 0):

That's no longer the recommended way of writing new tags. Microsoft XP tags are a particular problem since they claim to be of type byte, but the data is actually UTF-16LE.

Rather use the new API which takes care of all this - for example http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/commons/proper/imaging/trunk/src/test/java/org/apache/commons/imaging/formats/jpeg/exif/MicrosoftTagTest.java?view=markup

Comment: I very much like the new API but I am running into the exact same issue with the updated code. I can update the author just fine, but updates to xpkeywords produce no errors but do not modify the data. I'll update the question to use the new trunk commons-imaging syntax