# Accessing jpeg tags using java commons-imaging

Tags: java, image, jpeg, tiff, exif

How can i access(read/write) a jpeg image tags using **common-imaging** or **sanselan** in java, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36868013/editing-jpeg-exif-data-with-java/50221416?noredirect=1#comment87460378_50221416) has some explenation about the topic.

[image]

I tried the following code using the mentioned library as long as sanselan, but no affections.

```
public static void addImageHistoryTag(File file) {
    File dst = null;
    IImageMetadata metadata = null;
    JpegImageMetadata jpegMetadata = null;
    TiffImageMetadata exif = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    TiffOutputSet outputSet = new TiffOutputSet();

    // establish metadata
    try {
        metadata = Sanselan.getMetadata(file);
    } catch (ImageReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // establish jpegMedatadata
    if (metadata != null) {
        jpegMetadata = (JpegImageMetadata) metadata;
    }

    // establish exif
    if (jpegMetadata != null) {
        exif = jpegMetadata.getExif();
    }

    // establish outputSet
    if (exif != null) {
        try {
            outputSet = exif.getOutputSet();
        } catch (ImageWriteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if (outputSet != null) {
        // check if field already EXISTS - if so remove
        TiffOutputField imageHistoryPre = outputSet
                .findField(TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPCOMMENT);
        if (imageHistoryPre != null) {
            System.out.println("REMOVE");
            outputSet.removeField(TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPCOMMENT);
        }
        // add field
        try {
            String fieldData = "Hallo";
            TiffOutputField imageHistory = new TiffOutputField(
                    TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPTITLE,
                    TiffFieldTypeConstants.FIELD_TYPE_BYTE,
                    fieldData.length(),
                    fieldData.getBytes());

            TiffOutputDirectory exifDirectory = outputSet.getOrCreateExifDirectory();
            exifDirectory.removeField(TiffConstants.EXIF_TAG_XPTITLE);
            exifDirectory.add(imageHistory);

        } catch (ImageWriteException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        dst = new File("D:\\aa\\111.jpeg");
        os = new FileOutputStream(dst);
        os = new BufferedOutputStream(os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // write/update EXIF metadata to output stream
    try {
        new ExifRewriter().updateExifMetadataLossless(file,
                os, outputSet);
    } catch (ImageReadException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ImageWriteException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (os != null) {
            try {
                os.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not affect on the image details tags, So I am looking for the correct constant that can be used to access "tags field"

Comment: You used the [java] tag. You tried any Java code? What error did you find?

Comment: @Alfabravo I updated the question, please check it

Answer (score 0):

If you're using commons-imaging, don't use `Sanselan.getMetadata(file)`, Use `Imaging.getMetadata(file)` to be consistant. Sanselan was deprecated for commons-imaging, as far as i know.

Also, you might try setting [MicrosoftTagConstants](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-imaging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/imaging/formats/tiff/constants/MicrosoftTagConstants.html), specifically, `EXIF_TAG_XPKEYWORDS`. For that, you need to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25639015/236345).